# Complex integral on a circle

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the given integral:

$\int_{\gamma}\frac{z+1}{z^3-z}$

which has to be evaluated over $\gamma=|z+1-i|<2$.

I start by re-writing the integral by partial fractions inmo:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{z+1}{z^3-z}dz=-\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-1}dz+\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}dz
\end{equation}

Using Cauchy's formula,

\begin{equation}
f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}
\end{equation}

I get on the first term:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z-1}dz=2\pi i f(-1)=2\pi i \cdot (-1/2)=-i\pi
\end{equation}

But then the second term is not so easy, as $a=0$:

\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z+0}dz=2\pi i f(0)=2\pi i \cdot ?=?
\end{equation}

What should I do with the second term?

Thanks!

Comment: Decomposition of $\frac{z+1}{z^3-z}$ to partial fractions should include the term $\frac{C}{z^2}$ for some constant $C$. And if you're using Cauchy's formula, you must pay attention whether your $\gamma$ is around the point of singularity of denominator (otherwise the integral is $0$). Moreover, your function $f$ is not the whole $\frac{1}{z-1}$ (respectivelly $\frac{1}{z}$) in Cauchy's formula, but only the numerator, that is $f \equiv 1$.

Comment: But $\frac{z+1}{z^3-z}$ is simplified by canceling out one of the factors of $z^3-z$ out, so that C term is not necessary. a is inside the circle. Does this you say about f being 1, imply that Cauchys formula cannot be applied?

Comment: Of course, sorry, don't know why I thought that $0$ is the zero of second order. As for the question about circle, the point $a=1$ is outside $\gamma$ (because $|i-1 - 1| > 2$) so what Cauchy's formula tells you?

Comment: You're right, 1 is outside of that circle. What this implies for Cauchys formula is that it cannot be applied

Comment: Somehow it can be applied, however maybe you're not familiar with calling it Cauchy's formula. But if point is outside $\gamma$, and on open region containing $\gamma$ you have holomorphic function (and $\frac{1}{z-1}$ is holomorphic on some open region containing $\gamma$) then that integral over $\gamma$ must be equal to zero, because $\gamma$ is a closed curve.

Comment: How can I prove this?

Comment: It depends on what you already know. You sure that in your formulation of Cauchy's formula the case of point $a$ being outside $\gamma$ wasn't covered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132183/discussion-between-vqngs-and-dominik-kutek).